Over one thousand users!
This is just to observe, as I have just done, that in the last few hours we have passed the one-thousand mark for the number of users of this site. Admittedly, not all of them are active, and someone will have just made a one-time answer or question, but it is all the same a nice, round goal. Any idea how to reach the 2000 mark even faster?

Produce better content! Fix old questions which remain unanswered or without a satisfying answer! But most of all, use meaningful titles for questions! Cheers to Dag for this good news.

What @martina said! Nice work, everyone. :)

It is not exactly what you are asking for, but I've found this answer interesting, specially the part which recommends to be mindful of how we treat new users. We don't want only new users in the site, we want them to keep coming and participate.

E oggi abbiamo anche raggiunto la soglia di 2 domande al giorno. Alé!

If it is true that there are so many people learning Italian in the world, I feel that one of the the reasons that this site is not very active is simply that lots of potential users don't know about it. Thus, it can seem quite obvious, but maybe we should think about advertising the site more frequently in social networks, blogs, communities...  

Advertise the existence of this StackExchange site by sending e-mails to University Professors of Italian at English-speaking, Italian, Swiss Italian, and other universities throughout the world, as well as to teachers of Italian language teaching in various schools around the world, as well as post on social networks if at all possible.
I think it could work!
Regards.
